# Knapsack problem with value range constraint

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-optimization, proof-theory, integer-programming

The traditional knapsack problem is that: given a sequence of $i$ items with positive weights $w_1,w_2,...,w_i$, positive values $v_1,v_2,...,v_i$, and a bag with capacity $B$, we want to insert items into the bag without exceeding the capacity $B$ while maximising the total values (i.e., maximising $\sum_{h=1}^i p_h*v_h$ subject to (1) $p_h=0$ or 1, (2) $\sum_{h=1}^i p_h*w_h \leq B$ ). I know the decision problem of knapsack problem is NP-complete and thus the optimisation version is NP-hard.

But what if we have the constraint restricting each item value $v_h$ within the range $[0,w_h]$? Is it still Np-hard under this constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to enforce this constraint for a generic knapsack problem.
Indeed, it is enough just to multiply all $w_h$ and $B$ by $c:=\max_h \frac{v_h}{w_h}$. Then for any $h$,
$$v_h = \frac{v_h}{w_h} w_h\leq cw_h,$$
i.e. $v_h\in[0,cw_h]$, while the constraint $
\sum_h p_hw_h\leq B$ is equivalent to $\sum_h p_h(cw_h)\leq cB$.

Comment: So is my problem just a special case of the generic knapsack problem you formulated with c=1? If so, it may not be sufficient to prove the NP-hardness of my knapsack problem. Is it correct?

Comment: Vice versa, generic knapsack is reduced to your problem by multiplying its parameters by suitable $c$. This proves NP-hardness of your problem.

Comment: Hi Max, I have a follow up question. If I have one more constraint on $B$ which is $\sum_{h=1}^i (w_h+v_h)/2 =B$, is this problem still NP-hard?

Comment: @EricHuang: Yes, it's also NP-hard. To reduce your original problem to this new one, we can consider two cases. If $\sum_h (w_h+v_h)/2 < B$, we add a new "useless" item with $v_* := 0$ and $w_* := 2B - \sum_h (w_h+v_h)$. If $\sum_h (w_h+v_h)/2 > B$, we add a new "super useful" item with $v_* := 1 + \sum_h v_h$ and increase $B$ by its capacity $w_* := v_* + \sum_h (w_h+v_h) - 2B > v_*$, implying that $(w_* + v_*)/2 + \sum_h (w_h+v_h)/2 = B + w_*$.

Comment: Hi Max, based on my understanding of your reduction. When $\sum_{h} (w_h+v_h)/2<B$, we will never choose the useless item, and the solution of the new problem is the solution of my original problem. When $\sum_{h} (w_h+v_h)/2>B$, we will always choose the ``super useful" item and the solution of the new problem is the solution of my original problem plus the "super useful" item. But how we can make sure that the "super useful" item will be always chosen in the new problem? Otherwise, the introduced extra weight $w_*$ will impact the solution of my original problem.

Comment: @EricHuang: Super useful item is more useful than all other items altogether ($v_* > \sum_h v_h$), and so it must be present in the solution.

Comment: Btw, I know it is intuitive that multiplying all $w_h$ and $B$ by a parameter $c$ will not influence the solution. But it becomes tricky when you want to formalise this intuition. How can we formally show that multiplying by $c$ will result in the same solution?

Comment: @EricHuang: You show this by establishing correspondence between solutions to a new problem and solutions to the old one.

Comment: @EricHuang: Since we can accommodate this super useful item ($B^*:=B+w_*>w_*$), the optimal solution must include it.

Comment: I got your point about the "super useful" item. But I am still a little bit confused about the correspondence establishment about multiplying $c$.

Comment: @EricHuang: If you mean my answer, then correspondence is direct -- any solution $(p_h)$ to the new problem represents a solution to the old one as well.

Comment: Btw, I am very impressed by your reduction skill. How could you think of such nice reduction? Could you share some tips on doing reduction?

Comment: @EricHuang: Thanks, but that's just an experience. The more examples and techniques you know, the better vision you have for what can be done with a particular problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are a very nice person and I wish I could learn more from you.